# Validate comma separated string of numbers with Regular Expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for validation of 3 numbers then `,` and again 3 numbers and again basically any number of times. And comma can be at the begining or it can be at the end (but strictly one).

So, these are valid inputs:

> ,111,111,
>
> 112,112,
>
> ,112,112,113,114,111,
>
> ,114,115
>
> ,142,
>
> ,141

Invalid inputs:

> ,,
>
> ,    ,
>
> ,,145,,,

I have made like:

```
var re = /^[0-9]{3}([,][0-9]{3})*$/;
```

But it is not working well and it is only accepting 2 groups. And always want comma at the end.

Comment: yes  i have made  like **/^[0-9]{3}([,][0-9]{3})*$/;** But it is not working well and it is only accepting 2 groups. And always want comma at the end.

Comment: Which language are you using? Again, please [edit] your question; and see [the Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) for guidance and hints.

Comment: But you didn't want to edit that into the question? Sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
^,?(?:\d{3},)*\d{3},?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/33PmtC/1/)

Replace `\d` with `[0-9]` if it is not supported in your regex platform.

**RegRx Description:**

- `^,?`: Match an optional `,` at the start
- `(?:\d{3},)*`: Match a non-capturing group 0 or more times. We match a 3 digit number followed by `,` inside this group.
- `\d{3}`: Match a 3 digit number
- `,?$`: Match an optional `,` at the end

Comment: ,040,041, It is only accepting 2 groups not able to accept any digit after the last comma.

Comment: That's not true. `,040,041,` is being validated with this regex. See first example of `,111,111,`